# raspberry executing node js script via /etc/profile and desktop autostart

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I have this nodejs script that basically the job is spawning one python process and an appimage

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

let app;

app = function(){
    let python = cp.spawn('python3', ['qrcode.py']);

    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        
    });

    python.stderr.on(data,function(data){

    });

    python.on('close', (code) => {
        // respawn after 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            app();
        },5000);
    });
}

app();

// execute the appimage
cp.execFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/attrfidqrcode-1.0.0-armv7l.AppImage'), function(err, data) {

});
```

and tried to autostart via `/etc/profile` added to the bottom

```
node /home/pi/.dev/attendance-rfid-qrcode/app.js
```

and reboot but not working at all and I can verify it via `ps -e` and there are no processes like python or the appimage I'm expecting to appear

tried also desktop autostart

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi && touch ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and add symbolic link `ln -s .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart ~/autostart`

then `nano autostart` and insert with

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset dpms 0 0 0
@/home/pi/autostart.sh
```

then created the autostart.sh `nano autostart.sh` and make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/autostart.sh
```

and autostart.sh content

```
#!/bin/bash
node /home/pi/.dev/attendance-rfid-qrcode/app.js
```

but unfortunately, not working at all

Any ideas, help, suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
@node /home/pi/.dev/attendance-rfid-qrcode/app.js
```

at the end of

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi
```

This is how I launch chromium in my kiosks. If is doesn't work try to add at the end of the command something like `>> log_file 2>&1` to log `stderr` and `stdoout` and try to figure out what's happening.